# Problem obtaining web service response

Tags: .net, android

I made a web service REST in .NET which is succesfully conected with the app made in android, but the problem is that when I want to obtain the response, String in this case, I can't compare it inside the android app.

The problem is that if I've got `res` as my web service response, with a value of `"Err"` and  I do:

```
if (res == "Err")
```

It just says they do not match. What could be the problem?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It's not very clear. What do you mean by "Inside the android app"??

Answer (score 0):

Comparing strings in Java:

```
if(res.equals("Err")) {
 // equals
}
```

Comment: I'm doing like this, but I realize that the problem is that service response me also with the marks, I mean, "Err" and I'm not really sure if it's correct, my response type is JSON...

Comment: Ok, you need to rephrase your question then like Kumar advised. Your question will be - how to parse JSON :). Or search from SO for similar questions. There's thousands of them.